# How can I connect to local server?

Tags: server, connection, ftp

I am newbie on Ubuntu. So I am trying to learn how to implement some windows style commands in Ubuntu.
In Windows as you know that in order to connect to local server remotely you just need to type in `Run` followed by the name of the server. for example: \n2server
How can I connect to a server (within the same network) from Ubuntu terminal.
P.S. I am trying to connect to FTP server.

Comment: I did not know that you could FTP to a remote server from the Windows command line by entering \servername. I just tried this and it didn't work. Do you perhaps have a batch file with the name "servername.bat"?

Comment: Sorry. I mean I did it not CMD, but in "Run".

Comment: Ah, yes. When I try it I have to enter a *double* slash at the beginning. It brings up an Explorer window showing the files on the remote server. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start Nautilus by clicking on the filefolder icon in the launcher. Make sure that the Nautilus window is active. Select File | Connect to Server... from the top menu. A dialog box opens. For Type select "Public FTP" (or "Windows share" if you are accessing a SMB/CIFS/Samba file server). For Server enter the server name or IP address, and so on.

Comment: Good to hear. Please accept the answer so I get some reputation points for Valentine's Day. :)

Answer (score 2):

From the command line in a Terminal window, enter the following commmand.

```
ftp {user}:{password}@{server}
```

Change the {} parts to your username, password and server name, and if all goes well an ftp session will start allowing you to issue ftp commands, e.g., to get files from or put files to the server.